# "Statement is not valid in a namespace" error messaging

Tags: .net, vb.net

I Have a bit of a problem..For some reason visual studio says there's an error--it reads:

> Statement is not valid in  a namespace

I can't figure out how to fix it. This is what my coded looks like and there's a blue squiggly line on the first two lines that start with Private Sub:

```
Private Sub btnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click

'This procedure Starts the timer (progress bar) when the user clicks Play
'and it starts the game
Timer1.Start()
btnPlay.Enabled = True
picMainPage.Visible = False

End Sub
```

I hope someone can help, I'm new at this and I've been stuck with this error for three days now... :( I've tried various things from, adding END CLASS to the end of the code to re-witting the coded but I keep getting the same error message.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put methods within a *class* (or module or structure), not directly in a namespace.

See [Structure of a Visual Basic program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/022td33t.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read the info on the link you suggested and it turned out to be a quick, easy fix. All I had to do was add "End Class: at the very end of the last private sub instead of where I had it initially. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private Sub btnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click

        'This procedure Starts the timer (progress bar) when the user clicks Play
        'and it starts the game
        Timer1.Start()
        btnPlay.Enabled = True
        picMainPage.Visible = False

    End Sub
End Class
```