# Alternate ways of read, write data from multiple forms using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an application for work. We use an excel file to create reports. I am rusty in coding and really have not faced such a large request. The way the application works is there is standard toolbar. When the user opens the application he is presented with blank form. They must first create a new file and save it to their folder of choice. I have used the stream reader/writer but the problem is there is large amounts of data that user has to fillout so my code is horrible and monster like and I was wondering is there an easier way?

```
     ToolStripLabel1.Text = FileDataStorage.OpenFileTextBox1.Text
     If ToolStripLabel1.Text = ("C:\Temp\New QCA.qca") Then
        MsgBox("Must Save New file first ACCESS DENIED!")
        End If
     Dim FILE_NAME As String = FileDataStorage.OpenFileTextBox1.Text
    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(General_Data.GTextBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox12.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox13.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox14.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox15.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox16.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox17.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox18.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox19.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.ComboBox20.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox12.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox13.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox14.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox15.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox16.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox17.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox18.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox19.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox20.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox21.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox22.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox23.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox24.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox25.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox26.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox27.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox28.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox29.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox30.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox31.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox32.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox33.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox34.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox35.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox36.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox37.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox38.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox39.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox40.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox41.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox42.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox43.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox44.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox45.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox46.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox47.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox48.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox49.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox50.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox51.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox52.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox53.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox54.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox55.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox56.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox57.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox58.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox59.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox60.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox61.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox62.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox63.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox64.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox65.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox66.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox67.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox68.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox69.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox70.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox71.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox72.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox73.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox74.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox75.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox76.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox77.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox78.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox79.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Inventory.TextBox80.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.ComboBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.ComboBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Water_QC.TextBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox12.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox13.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox14.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox15.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox16.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox17.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox18.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox19.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox20.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox21.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox22.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox23.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox24.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox25.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox26.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox27.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox28.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox29.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox30.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox31.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox32.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox33.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox34.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Base_Gel_QC.TextBox35.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox2.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox4.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox5.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox6.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox7.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox8.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox9.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox10.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox11.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox12.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox13.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox14.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox15.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox16.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox17.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox18.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox19.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox20.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox21.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox22.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox23.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox24.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox25.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox26.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox27.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox28.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox29.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox30.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox31.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox32.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox33.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox34.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox35.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox36.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox37.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox38.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox39.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox40.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox41.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox42.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox43.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox44.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox45.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox46.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox47.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox48.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox49.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox50.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox51.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox52.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox53.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox54.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox55.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox56.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox57.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox58.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox59.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox60.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox61.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox62.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox63.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox64.Text)
            objWriter.WriteLine(Acid_QC.TextBox65.Text)



            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Data written to file")

        Else

            'Do Nothing

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean making the code more elegant?  You could do something like the following.

```
    ToolStripLabel1.Text = FileDataStorage.OpenFileTextBox1.Text

    If ToolStripLabel1.Text = ("C:\Temp\New QCA.qca") Then
        MsgBox("Must Save New file first ACCESS DENIED!")
    End If

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = FileDataStorage.OpenFileTextBox1.Text

    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            For Each c As Control In Form.Controls
                If TypeOf c Is TextBox Or TypeOf c Is ComboBox Then
                    objWriter.WriteLine(c.Text)
                End If
            Next

            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Data written to file")

         Else
            'Do Nothing
         End If
    Catch ex As Exception
         Throw
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with what you have already, an external function similar to this may work for you.
It goes over the form passed to it, and then finds the objects of a certain type, and then prints them out to the writer that you've created there. You'll have to make it work with what you have already, but something like this would save so many lines.

What it does is gets the number of controls on the form, and then goes across each one to get its type. If the type is correct, then it just writes its contents to the file.

```
Private sub writeToFile(formFrom as Form)
    Dim controls As Control
    For Each controls In formFrom.Controls
        If TypeOf (controls) Is TextBox Then
            objWriter.WriteLine(formFrom.controls.text)
        elseif TypeOf (controls) is ComboBox then
            objWriter.WriteLine(formFrom.controls.text)
        End If
    Next
end sub
```

Comment: I get a Statement is not valid name space on for the first line

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219886/statement-is-not-valid-in-a-namespace-error-messaging) may help you with that.

Comment: Sounds like you may have put Gyhth's writeToFile method outside of the class.